# In Snowflake, why, when you assign two variables at the same time, is there a 256 byte limit on the variables?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using Snowflake, trying to set two variables at the same time to a result set with two fields, but it's not working how I thought it would. Here's an example:

When I run this:

```
set (var1, var2) = (select 'IIIIIIIIII----------IIIIIIIIII----------IIIIIIIIII----------IIIIIIIIII','');
```

I get the following error:

```
Assignment to 'VAR1' not done because value exceeds size limit for variables. Its size is 280; the limit is 256 (internal storage size in bytes).
```

However, this works fine (same number of characters):

```
set (var1) = (select 'IIIIIIIIII----------IIIIIIIIII----------IIIIIIIIII----------IIIIIIIIII');
```

It seems that when assigning *two* variables the length of the string of one of the fields can only be 256 bytes. When working with 4-byte characters, my 70-character string above is 280 characters, blowing the 256 limit.

I'm thinking this maybe has to do with how the storage of the variable collection is in an array- or tuple-like datatype that doesn't support more than 256 bytes? But I'm struggling to confirm this through the documentation.

Comment: Interestingly, if you take the select out of the assignment, it works:  set (var1, var2) = ('IIIIIIIIII----------IIIIIIIIII----------IIIIIIIIII----------IIIIIIIIII','');

Comment: Yeah, that is actually interesting! I hadn't noticed that. Unfortunately, the problem I'm actually trying to solve requires a select statement that returns two values. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually stated in the documentation for the SET operator:

> Usage Notes
>
> The command supports setting multiple variables in the
>   same statement.
>
> If the command executing complex expressions, it might require a
>   running virtual warehouse in the session.
>
> The number of expressions must match the number of variables to
>   initialize.
>
> **> The size of string or binary variables is limited to 256 bytes.**
>
> The identifier (i.e. name) for a SQL variable is limited to 256
>   characters.
>
> Variable names such as CURRENT or PUBLIC are reserved for future use
>   by Snowflake and cannot be used.

However, in regards to your example it also seems that it can be accomplished by two SELECTs within the same SET operation - like this:

```
set (var1, var2) = (
  (select ''),
  (select 'IIIIIIIIII----------IIIIIIIIII----------IIIIIIIIII----------IIIIIIIIII')
);
```